# bind is not validating dnssec

Tags: linux, bind, dnssec

Strange. My bind is not validating dnssec even though I configured it to.  Version according to `named -V` is `BIND 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.10.rc1.el6_3.2` which has a built-in DLV key.

Under options in named.conf

```
dnssec-enable yes;
dnssec-validation yes;
dnssec-lookaside auto;
```

But when I query a known bad zone, like doing `dig www.dnssec-failed.org @localhost` I get IP addresses- not a failure like I was expecting. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't ask why, but I had the same issue and setting dnssec-validation option to auto instead of yes fixed the issue

Comment: That worked.  Thanks. `dnssec-validation auto` and now I get a failure when trying to resolve a bad signed zone.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [reference manual](ftp://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#Configuration_File_Grammar),

> "dnssec-validation"
>
> [...]
>
> If set to "auto", DNSSEC validation is enabled, and a default trust-anchor for the DNS root zone is used.
>
> If set to "yes", DNSSEC validation is enabled, but a trust anchor must be manually configured using a "trusted-keys" or "managed-keys" statement.

Therefore, you must either set it to `auto` mode, or explicitly `include "/etc/bind.keys"`.

Answer (score 0):

If set to "auto", DNSSEC validation is enabled, and a default trust-anchor for the DNS root zone is used.

the default trust-anchor used is from bind.keys, a default is preloaded out of the box